# Looking to raise an exception if disconnect occurs and restart the main method in a separate file. How should I implement this?

Tags: python, exception

If disconnect is called, I want to restart the main method from the connection.py file. Main method does not restart with existing code when disconnect occurs.

connection.py file*

```
def disconnect(flags):
    #do something
    raise RuntimeError('You have been disconnected')
```

main.py file*

```
import connection

def main():

while True:
     try: 
         #do something to invoke disconnect
     except RuntimeError('You have been disconnected'):
         main()

 main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your try-except block is wrong. I ran your code in python3, and it raised a very clear error, "builtins.TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed" Because of that unhandled exception, you exit main.

Try these:

```
try: 
    raise RuntimeError('You have been disconnected')
except RuntimeError:
    print ('caught')

try: 
    raise RuntimeError('You have been disconnected')
except RuntimeError as e:
    print (str(e))
```

Because you already have a while loop in main, there's no need to recursively call main again. Just let the while loop do its job:

```
def main():
    while True:            
        connect()                            
        try: 
            raise RuntimeError('You have been disconnected')
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print (str(e))
```

If the error is caught, then you will still be inside the while loop.

Comment: And still raise the RuntimeError('You have been disconnected') within the disconnect method?

Comment: Oh yes ... I just did it directly there because I was demonstrating the "except" working or not working. You would want to raise it when it actually happens, yes. It would be silly to raise an exception just to catch it on the next line in real code.